# Is it illegal to voluntarily work longer than the law allows?

Tags: germany, workplace, finland

Let Bob be a software developer that can work from home. Bob's contract says he has to work 40h/week. The employer offers a flexible distribution of those hours and doesn't care when Bob works, as long as he averages 40h/week. To absolutely push this question, let's assume Bob can work uninterruptedly without feeling effects of fatigue or loss in concentration.
This is an obvious hyperbole to explore the law and not about questionable work practices/ethics.

I know that some countries set upper limits on how many hours a day/a week you may work. But I suppose this is to protect the employee from their employer, who otherwise theoretically might force them to stay indefinitely at work. However, does this also force the employee to stop working?

When bob is in the zone he just doesn't want to stop working. He voluntarily stays as long as he needs to get the job done. There is no emergency or other situation that requires urgent care.

- Can Bob legally work 40hours in 2 days and take the rest of the week off?
- Can Bob legally work 80hours in 1 week and take every other week off?

Comment: Note that the line between "Bob is doing it of their own free will" and "Bob has done it because they felt pressured by their employer" is pretty blurry and in many country there are probably enough precedents that the law would always take Bob's side if Bob decided to accuse their employer of pressuring them into this.

Comment: The weekly work limit in Germany according to the [Arbeitszeitgesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/BJNR117100994.html) is actually 48 hours, not 40 hours. While §3 of the law says that the average time per work-day is 8 hours, §1(2) of the law also says that only Saturday is free, which means there are 6 work-days per week as far as this law is concerned.

Comment: @Philipp the contract says 40hours. 80 hours would still be above the limit, no matter if it's 40 or 48. Also you surely mean sunday, not saturday. But still, for the purpose of the question assume Bob would only work on non-holidays.

Comment: Not an answer since it wasn't your question, just as information for other nationalities reading this and wondering... you can work as long as you want, if you are *self-employed*. You can exploit yourself as much as you want. That it is your own problem. But regular employees are protected by law.

Comment: @nvoigt Indeed, Arbeitszeitgesetz does not regulate self-employed people at all.

Comment: @nvoigt I suspect "_as long as you want, if you are self-employed_"  won't apply for all jobs. For instance, in the UK (and I assume Germany), bus/coach/lorry drivers' hours are heavily regulated, and I'm fairly sure you can't ignore them just by being self-employed.

Comment: @TripeHound No, but the hours are regulated by public road safety laws, not labor laws. If you buy private property, you can drive your bus there in circles as long as you want as a self-employed person, but an employer cannot make their employee drive a bus on private/company property as long as they want. So yeah, you can work as long as you want as self-employed person... your work still has to adhere to all other laws, they don't cease to exist.

Comment: @TripeHound Or to explain it in another way: Neither self-employed nor employed drivers are allowed to drive longer than mandated by traffic laws, or they risk losing their drivers license. But a self-employed person who exceeded their maximum safe driving time could then perform other work-related tasks like loading, unloading, truck maintenance or doing paperwork until they literally drop dead.

Comment: @Philipp though the traffic laws mandate **rest** before he is allowed to drive again.

Comment: @Trish Of course they do. What has that to do with my comment?

Comment: "I suppose this is to protect the employee from their employer". I think this really is a wrong assumption. I believe that the law is mostly simply there for the employee's health and safety. It is simply deemed unhealthy to work more than that. Although this is also merely an assumption of mine

Comment: An interesting question arises when there are other factors. For example, say there is an understaffed Emergency Hospital. It can be that doctors MUST man the hospital 24/7 with a minimum set of staff specified by law, but doing so means that they MUST work way more than legally allowed and won't be able to take the legally mandated rests. What should doctors do? Whatever they do they break the law. (And this is not even so much hypothetical, in many places healthcare is very near this point).

Answer (score 29):

### No, your employer has to actively stop you from this in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

The Arbeitszeitgeseztz is very clear in regards to maximum permittable time per day: 8 hours of work time on at most 6 days a week (Monday - Saturday) are allowed under normal circumstances.

Only in exceptional cases, **10 hours on a single day** on the 6 work days in a week can be permissible. Even then the **average work time may not exceed 8 hours per day worked** over 6 months/24 weeks. That is regulated in the Worktime Law §3.

If the work contract mandates fewer hours or days, that does not change the allowable time per day at all: if you have a 2-day week, you may work 8 hours on both days regularly, and 10 only when your average hours per day over 6 months stays at or under 8 hours.

> [ArbZG §3](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__3.html): Die werktägliche Arbeitszeit der Arbeitnehmer darf acht Stunden nicht überschreiten. Sie kann auf bis zu zehn Stunden nur verlängert werden, wenn innerhalb von sechs Kalendermonaten oder innerhalb von 24 Wochen im Durchschnitt acht Stunden werktäglich nicht überschritten werden.

This is **strict liability** - intent does not matter, it doesn't matter that the employee instigated it. The employer is on the hook for up to 30 000 € per case according to [ArbZG §22](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__22.html). Unscheduled audits from the official side on performed work hours, following documentation requirements and related issues happen, among others, in construction or road transport regularly. You'd be surprised: Customs and Border Police is tasked with enforcing those requirements on truckers and construction crews.

Among the employer's duties is to keep their employee healthy, which includes sending them home after 8/10 hours, not giving them work (or time!) till they have had [a chance for his mandatory rest time under ArbZG §5](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/__5.html) of 11 hours, and to send them home if they exceed the allowable average work time over 6 months and forcing them to take time off. It even can include forcing the employee to take holidays so they can rest and recuperate!

> [Assume] the contract says 40hours. [...] For the purpose of the question assume Bob would only work on non-holidays.

Under german ArbZG this number can allow a lot of variation, such as all these that are designed to balance out within one week for simpler math reasons:

- 6 days at 6 hours, 40 minutes, plus-minus a little overtime
- 5 days per week at 8 hours on average, sometimes a little more, sometimes a little less.
- as an extreme case: contractually 5 days are contracted for, the employee is only working 4 days per week at 10 hours (2 of them 'overtime') and always takes the 5th day fully off from the accrued overtime.

Comment: The "eight hours per workday", is that 8 x 5 hours a week? Or per day that I actually work? Would it be legal to work 11 hours on Monday and Tuesday and have the rest of the week off?

Comment: @gnasher729 Per day that you work. And you can under **no** circumstanced to 11 hours, you are limited at 10 per day you work. Clarified for convenience.

Comment: @gnasher729 And the ArbZG spake, saying, ''First shalt thou take out the Holy Pin. Then shalt thou count to ten, no more, no less. Ten shall be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be Ten. Eleven shalt thou not count, neither count thou Nine, excepting that thou then proceed to Ten. Twelve is right out.  Once the number Ten, being the tenth number, be reached, then stoppest all thy worketh and goeth home, no matter who, being naughty in My sight, shall demand otherwise."

Comment: @gnasher729: The rules are: maximum of 8 hours per workday on average, maximum of 10 hours on any given workday, maximum length of a workday of 12 hours (that is, from the first time you start working until the last time you stop working, including all breaks), 11 hours of rest from the end of the workday to the start of the next. There are all sorts of subtleties and exceptions, e.g. for hospital workers, or for on-call periods, but that's the standard rules in the standard case.

Comment: One curiosity of employee protection laws is that only the employer can violate them. The legal theory behind that is that the employer is in a position of power, so the assumption is that if an employ***ee*** violates the law, they were either a) forced by their employer or b) the employer was in a position to stop them and didn't.

Comment: "Customs and Border Police is tasked with enforcing those requirements on truckers and construction crews." well, the former definitely have definitive tracking devices (tachographs) that make this situation strictly enforceable and for a reason - tired truckers have a tendency to do a lot of damage. But the question is about software developers and I'm not sure they're being audited in quite the same manner.

Comment: @roganjosh those get audited by the Arbeitsschutzbehörde, if at all.

Comment: @roganjosh Employers are required to document the working hours of their employees and the Arbeitsschutzbehörde can ask for those documents. Turns out it's not that easy to believably fake working hours over a long period of time (particularly if the employees want to get paid for the time they worked)

Comment: @roganjosh ...and **especially** with programmers, who work on multiple bits of source code and use version-history programming software - which automatically saves pretty much every line of code entered in about 5-10 minute increments together with who made the edits. A forensic expert could reasonably re-create accurate working hours from the changelog of the files worked on. // In a related manner: when home office became suddenly mandated during COVID 19, the Arbeitsschutzbehörde did give quite some leeway for home office workers, as long as after their request measures were implemented.

Comment: @Trish not _really_ the point but I've been a developer for the best part of a decade and worked with at least three difference version control systems. I've never encountered one which automatically saved my work for me.

Comment: @Trish One should note, though, that in practice very many people work more than 10 hours a day. This is publicly known and nobody cares, unless the Betriebsrat (if it exists) does something about it. To give examples: Low paid workers like scaffolders or parcel delivery persons often work 12-14 hours a day. Also highly paid consultants. I even know somebody who was told in the job interview that work is "from 8a.m. to 8p.m. with 30 minutes lunch break".

Comment: @JFabianMeier parcel drivers are commonly self employed contractors. The company employed employees can only work 10 hours and are required to take their 45 minute break

Comment: @Trish At least for the people on my construction site I know that they worked 12-14 hours a day. And they were employees. I also know somebody personally who was told to not write down any overtime he worked, otherwise this would be a career ending move. So he wrote down 35 hours a week instead of 45. I just wanted to note that it is common to work more than 10 hours a day despite there is a law against.

Comment: Ah yes, the blatant ignorance to the time laws on constriuction are well known - which is why customs randomly comes to construction times. But as long as all are silent and records routinely doctored with... nothing can be done.

Answer (score 14):

This question can be answered for [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) by looking into the [Arbeitszeitgesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/arbzg/BJNR117100994.html). All the clauses mentioned in this answer represent clauses from this law.

> Can Bob legally work 40hours in 2 days and take the rest of the week off?

> Can Bob legally work 80hours in 1 week and take every other week off?

No, these scenarios would both be illegal.

§3 says that the maximum work time *each* day is 10 hours, and the maximum work time *on average* must not exceed 8 hours. However, §1 only defines Sunday as a free day, which means that there are actually 6 work-days in a week, which means the maximum average weekly work hours allowed by law are 48.

So the most Bob would be allowed to do is to work 6 day weeks with 10 hour days. Each of those weeks would accrue 12 hours of overtime, which means that for each 4 weeks Bob works that way he would need to take one full week off.

Also relevant might be §5, which says that there must be a break of at least 11 hours between leaving work on one day and resuming work on the next day.

If Bob voluntarily works more than the legal limits, then the one who is on the hook would be the employer. §22 mandates fines up to 30,000€. In extreme cases of repeated offenses, §23 allows even a 1 year prison sentence. Violating labor time laws is not an [*Antragsdelikt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antragsdelikt), so the state can persecute them regardless of whether or not Bob wants them to.

Comment: due to balancing out allowing for 6 months accrued overtime, the math goes a little more stacked: ~4 months of all-days10-hour shifts, a whole month off.

Comment: Note that the Arbeitszeitgesetz does not apply to "Führungskräfte und leitende Angestellte". Not the case for a normal software developer, but certain higher technical positions can qualify, at which point this is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### [Maximum weekly hours](https://www.fairwork.gov.au/tools-and-resources/fact-sheets/minimum-workplace-entitlements/maximum-weekly-hours)

The National Employment Standards (NES) apply to all employees in the Federal System, anyone working for the Federal Government or a Constitutional Corporation i.e. companies, which means most employees except State or Territory Government employees.

The Maximum Weekly Hours for a full-time employee is 38 hours.

These may be subject to agreed averaging over a maximum of 26 weeks. For example, in FIFO jobs there may be 2 weeks on where 152 hours are worked, followed by 2 weeks off where no hours are worked - this would meet the requirements.

The employer may request and the employee must work reasonable additional hours.

> In determining whether additional hours are reasonable or unreasonable, the following must be taken into account:
>
> - any risk to employee health and safety
> - the employee’s personal circumstances, including family responsibilities
> - the needs of the workplace or enterprise
> - whether the employee is entitled to receive overtime payments, penalty rates or other compensation for (or a level of remuneration that reflects an expectation of ) working additional hours
> - any notice given by the employer to work the additional hours
> - any notice given by the employee of his or her intention to refuse to work the additional hours
> - the usual patterns of work in the industry
> - the nature of the employee’s role and the employee’s level of responsibility
> - whether the additional hours are in accordance with averaging provisions included in an award or agreement that is applicable to the employee, or an averaging arrangement agreed to by an employer and an award/agreement-free employee
> - any other relevant matter.

An employee who works additional hours without the employer requesting them is not entitled to payment for them, but there is no obligation on the employer to stop this happening. However, an employer who tolerates an expectation among their workforce that this is the "norm" may be deemed to have made an implicit request and be obliged to pay, and such hours would be subject to the reasonableness test.